# Who grades the mathematics phd comprehensive exams?

Tags: phd, mathematics, exams, qualifying-exam

Is it a committee of professors, or is it one professor -- whomever wrote the exams?

Comment: In general if you have a question about the way *your* department does business, you should ask people in your department.  Asking the question on a worldwide scale is throwing away so much information particular to your case, so is going to make a good answer at best difficult and inefficient to get.  **As a student in a university, it's okay to ask how things work.  In fact, it's encouraged.**

Comment: In my department, the exams are usually graded by two professors. They each grade the exams independently and then compare their grades (question by question) and resolve any nontrivial disagreements. (It's been a while since I was on a qualifying exams committee, so the arrangement could have changed, but I don't think it has.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd think a committee is much more likely than an individual professor, but I suppose it could depend on the size of the graduate program.  Comprehensive exams are handled in many different ways in different departments (when they are held at all), so there's no way to give a universal answer.  For example, in some departments the grading is delegated to junior faculty, while in others it isn't.  If you are interested in the answer in your own department, you'll have to ask them.